# default slider which sets same value for all other sliders

Tags: angular

I have a bunch of sliders as shown in the below picture. In that picture, you can see there is one `Default Slider`. This slider should set the same value to all other sliders and also other sliders can set their own value irrespective of `Default slider`.

```js
  my_ratings: Array<JSON> = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMyRatings();
}
  
  
  getMyRatings() {
    this.resetRatings();
    this.my_ratings = this.my_ratings || [];
    
    // show owner rating
    if (this.question.answer) {
      if (this.question.answer._user == this.userService.getValue()['_id']) {
        if (this.question.answer.all_ratings.owner.ratings.length > 0) {
          this.my_ratings = this.question.answer.all_ratings.owner.ratings;

          this.rating_factors.forEach((f, i) => f['my_rating'] = this.my_ratings[i]['score']);

        }
      }
      // get and set experts ratings in the interface 
      else {
        if (this.userService.getValue()['type'] == 'admin' && this.userService.getValue()['evaluator']) {
          let ei = this.question.answer.all_ratings.experts.map(e => e._user).indexOf(this.userService.getValue()['_id']);

          if (ei > -1) {
            this.my_ratings = this.question.answer.all_ratings.experts[ei].ratings;
            this.rating_factors.forEach((f, i) => f['my_rating'] = 
            
  this.my_ratings[i]['score']);
          }
        }
        // get and set others ratings in the interface
        else {
          let oi = this.question.answer.all_ratings.others.map(o => o._user).indexOf(this.userService.getValue()['_id']);

          if (oi > -1) {
            this.my_ratings = this.question.answer.all_ratings.others[oi].ratings;
            this.rating_factors.forEach((f, i) => f['my_rating'] = this.my_ratings[i]['score']);
          }
        }
      }

      if (!this.norelated)
        this.getRelUploads(this.question._id);
    }
  }
  
  
  resetRatings() {
    this.rating_factors['rater'] = 'me';
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    this.rating_factors.forEach((f, i) => f['my_rating'] = 0);
  }
```

```html
<div  class="factor animated slide">
          <div class="factor-name">
            <div>
              <img [src]="factor?.icon_url" style="height:30px;width:30px;">&nbsp;
              <label class="factor-label">Default Slider</label>
              <div class="tooltip" style="display: inline;">
                <i class="fa fa-question" style="width: 15px;
                  height: 15px;
                  padding: 2px 0 0 4px;opacity:0.7;
                  float: right;color:white;background-color: var(--primarycolor);border-radius: 50%;"></i>
                <span class="tooltiptext">Set all other values</span>

              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
          <div class="wrap">
            <input  name="range" type="range" class="range-slider__range" [(ngModel)]="masterRangeslider" 
            [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(90deg, hsl('+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +', 90%, 50%) '+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +'%, #d7dcdf 0%)'  }"
                  min="0" max="10">
            <div class="rating" [ngStyle]="{ 'left': ((10 * masterRangeslider) - 3) + '%' }">{{masterRangeslider}}</div>
          </div>
          <b>{{masterRangeslider || 0}}/10</b>
        </div>
      </div>

        
 <div *ngFor="let factor of rating_factors; let i = index" class="factor animated slide">
          <div class="factor-name">
            <div>
              <img [src]="factor?.icon_url" style="height:30px;width:30px;">&nbsp;
              <label class="factor-label">{{ factor.name }}</label>
              <div class="tooltip" style="display: inline;">
                <i class="fa fa-question" style="width: 15px;
                  height: 15px;
                  padding: 2px 0 0 4px;opacity:0.7;
                  float: right;color:white;background-color: var(--primarycolor);border-radius: 50%;"></i>
                <span class="tooltiptext">{{ factor.about }}</span>

              </div>
            </div>
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
            <div class="wrap">
              <input name="range" type="range" class="range-slider__range" [(ngModel)]="factor['my_rating']" 
                    [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(90deg, hsl('+ (10 * factor['my_rating']) +', 90%, 50%) '+ (10 * factor['my_rating']) +'%, #d7dcdf 0%)'  }"
                    min="0" max="10">
              <div class="rating" [ngStyle]="{ 'left': ((10 * factor['my_rating']) - 3) + '%' }">{{factor['my_rating']}}</div>
            </div>
            <b>{{factor['my_rating'] || 0}}/10</b>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Need explanation and stackblitz demo!

Comment: ok I will add now.

Comment: in terms of what do you expect or what is current output?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale the current output is just slider values and I have added default slider which should set all other slider values like if default slider is set to 1 all other sliders should also set to 1. if it is 5 all other sliders should also set to 5. along with that user sometimes choose a different value for each slider at that time he can make use of other sliders and can set his value to each slider that shouldn't affect the default slider. it is similar to an equalizer in music apps. you can select rock, pop or others based on that value it will set the bass, treble and others.

Comment: Yes got your requirement! Can you provide stackblitz demo with above (working) code?

Comment: code is big like it includes several services and HTTP interceptors. the code I have added above is good. you can check it out. you can easily understand.

Comment: just add your code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j34s19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can observe the change on your default slider so that each time you change its value, you reset the models values of all other sliders to the one of the master.

First listen for changes on the default slider (adding **change listener**):

```html
<input  name="range" type="range" class="range-slider__range" [(ngModel)]="masterRangeslider" 
            [ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'linear-gradient(90deg, hsl('+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +', 90%, 50%) '+ (10 * masterRangeslider) +'%, #d7dcdf 0%)'  }"
                  min="0" max="10" (change)="onDefaultSliderChange()">
```

Second reset the models values of all others sliders in your component:

```html
onDefaultSliderChange() {
    // Reset here all your other slider models value with the one from the default slider
    this.rating_factors.forEach((f, i) => f['my_rating'] = this.masterRangeslider);
    
    }
```

Comment: Where does this variable come from then?

Comment: `*ngFor="let factor of rating_factors;` from html

Comment: Ok then you have the rating_factors variable in your component. So you just need to give the index of the factor you want to update if that make sense?

Comment: Could you update your post in the first post with the .TS component please?

Comment: Thanks, so I have edited my code above so now it shows you how to update all the rating_factors in your component when you default slider value changes.